# Android - Complex query in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following SQL database:
  [Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0JnK.png)
I converted this to a JSON object, and import to Firebase.
Can I use complex queries here? Or shouldn't I use this, in my case?
I'm new in databases, especially in firebase, so I would appreciate some help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by complex queries? For your information, Firebase Realtime Database is a NoSQL database. [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)

Comment: for example, I want to filter data from 3-4 tables, in one query.
I know it's a NoSQL database, but after searching, I found some solutions for simple/short queries, from 2 table.
My database is relational, but is there any way to query data from e.g. 4 tables, in one query, with NoSQL?

Comment: I am afraid, no is the answer upto my knowledge; as `join`, etc type querying is not possible with Firebase Realtime Database.

Comment: SELECT bus_number.CodeNumber AS BusNumber,bus_Number.BusRouteName AS Routename, bus_route_type.OriginStopID AS Start, departure.StartTime as Time 
FROM bus_number,bus_route_type,departure,schedule_type
WHERE bus_number.CodeNumber LIKE "3A" AND schedule_type.ScheduleTypeName LIKE "2" 

(no INNER JOIN, 'cause it's too long :) )


here is a short example  for what I want to query. 
If it's not possible, is there a Cloud based SQL database for android, which is better? Real time is important

Comment: Querying each different table is like a different query each time. You'll not be able to get this result in a single query.

Comment: When you're using a NoSQL database, you're best off stopping to think of SQL queries. There is no simple mapping between the two. If you want to use SQL queries (there's nothing wrong with that), use a SQL database. When you use a NoSQL database, think in NoSQL structures and access patterns. To learn about this, read [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watch [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Shoudln't you remove the SQL tag from this question?